# Move multiple non adjacent rows on same sheet

Tags: google-sheets, move

I am trying to move non-adjacent rows to specific rows on the same sheet but I can't get it to work.  I have the following code so far:

```
    function moveRows() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rowSpec = sheet.getRangeList(["B11","B15"]);
sheet.moveRows("B2","B12")
}
```

This however returns the following error:

> Exception: The parameters (String,String) don't match the method
> signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.moveRows. moveRows @ Code.gs:4

From my searches, I haven't found a way to move multiple non-adjacent rows, so my first question is: Is it possible?

If not, is there a workaround and if so, how?

This is the sheet I am working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BKOxgZmAIoAzpmrF5NBChjFMXheyUEkf7SXVXCJs3zw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `var rowSpec = sheet.getRangeList(["B11","B15"]);` is not used.
- The arguments of `moveRows(rowSpec, destinationIndex)` are `rowSpec` (Range) and `destinationIndex` (Integer).
- From `I am trying to move non-adjacent rows to specific rows on the same sheet` and your showing script, I thought that you might want to move from row 2 to row 12. If my understanding is correct, how about modifying it as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function moveRows2() {
  var obj = [{"fromRow": 2, "toRow": 12}];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  obj.forEach(({fromRow, toRow}) =>
    sheet.moveRows(sheet.getRange(`${fromRow}:${fromRow}`), toRow)
  );
}
```

- When this script is run, row 2 is moved to row 11.
- If you want to move other rows, please add it to `obj` like `var obj = [{"fromRow": 2, "toRow": 12}, {"fromRow": 3, "toRow": 13},,,]`.
- Or, from your script, if you want to move cell "B2" to cell "B12", how about the following modification?

  ```
    var obj = [{"fromCell": "B2", "toCell": "B12"}];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    obj.forEach(({fromCell, toCell}) =>
      sheet.getRange(fromCell).moveTo(sheet.getRange(toCell))
    );
  ```

  - In this case, the cell after the cell value was moved becomes empty.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [moveRows(rowSpec, destinationIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#moverowsrowspec,-destinationindex)

Comment: Your first solution seems to have done exactly what I was looking to do. I wasn't aware this could be written like this. Thank you!

Comment: @Yannis Volos Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.